# Internal Server Error with template / Livelink WCMS 9.5.1

Tags: java, jsp, livelink

i just ran into some serious problems with a historic Livelink system - WCMS-Server 9.5.1.
I added a JSP-Topic secondary to another using the same template that prevails at the parent topics. Even though they work great with the parent topics, i can't find out why i get an Internal Server Error 500 when trying to preview them in edit-mode. Secondary Topics have basically the same settings. 
Same for JSP-Page. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: Tomcat says Nullpointer. catalina.out says NullPointer (no further details). Nothing seems missing.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:395)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
 de.gauss.vip.vipsecure.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:588)
 de.gauss.vip.vipsecure.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:486)